# I have two versions of Kernel on Kubuntu. How return back?

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu [18.04](/questions/tagged/18.04). In the past, I had followed some procedures **(** *`I don't remember them any more`* **)** to use Kernel version 5.x instead of 4.x. Now, grub shows up the two kernels and both of them receive updates. However, the working kernel by default now is the 5.x.

I need to return back to the 4.x kernel to be the default kernel and keeping the 5.x.

I have tried to enter in the grub menu during booting and choosing the 4.x kernel, but it only boots in that kernel for just the current session only.

Comment: You probably enabled HWE (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) which would cause the original 4.15 kernel to move to the 4.18 (18.10), 5.0 (19.04), 5.3 (19.10) & eventually 20.04 kernel. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack though `history` will display your command history useful to refresh memory (esp. if you have it record date/times too).  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup esp. Grub Default for changing the default OS options.